# Pytorch forecasting TimeSeriesDataSet Can't set min encoder length larger than 0

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-forecasting

I am trying to build a transformer for forecasting on my data. I have hourly data with no missing values or dates that's why I am using the datetime as index on my original dataframe. **My goal is to use 72 hours lookback to predict 24 hours ahead.** This is what my dataframe looks like.

```
|Date|Streamflow|Tmean|Tmin|Tmax|SolRad|Precipitation|windSp|
|2017-07-04 14:00:00|1520|13.58|13.2|14.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|2017-07-04 15:00:00|1520|13.85|13.5|14.7|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|2017-07-04 16:00:00|1520|14.15|13.9|14.4|1.7|0.0|0.0|
|2017-07-04 17:00:00|1446|14.25|14.2|14.3|0.0|0.0|0.0|
|2017-07-04 18:00:00|1592|14.26|14.1|14.4|0.0|0.0|0.0|
```

The issue I'm dealing with has probably something to do with the **time_idx** needed for TimeseriesDataset.

```
# Define features, target, and time index
# Including time_idx as a feature seemed necessary for the code to work
features = ['Precipitation', 'Tmean','Tmin','Tmax','SolRad','windSp','time_idx']
target = 'Streamflow'
time_idx = 'time_idx'
training_split =pd.to_datetime("2020-04-11")  # day for cutoff
data=df[df.index < training_split]
```

Since I can use the date as index I thought to define the time_idx in these two ways that both failed.

```
data['time_idx'] = range(len(data))
data["time_idx"] = (data.index - data.index.min()).total_seconds() // (3600 * 24)
```

Using these values I did not manage to load my data to the time series

```
min_prediction_length = 1
min_encoder_length=24

max_prediction_length = 24
max_encoder_length = 72
```

I get the error

> AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries - check encoder/decoder lengths and lags

By looking at the source code I figured that only thing that seemed to work was this setting that causes problems due to small encoder length

```
max_encoder_length=72,
min_encoder_length=0,
min_prediction_idx=0,
min_prediction_length=1,
max_prediction_length=24,
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my time index the problem ? I tried reproducing the source code to see whats wrong and also tried different indices but nothing seems to be working.

```
training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    data=data,
    time_idx="time_idx",
    target="Streamflow",
    group_ids=features,
    min_encoder_length=0, 
    max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
    min_prediction_length=1,
    max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
    time_varying_known_reals=features,
    time_varying_unknown_reals=["Streamflow"],
    target_normalizer=TorchNormalizer(),
    add_relative_time_idx=False,
    add_target_scales=True,
    add_encoder_length=True
)
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.